# GitHub Actions -- mark intentionally failed runs as success

Tags: github-actions

Say I have CI tests running via GitHub actions. The program I test has a module that checks whether its input parameters are valid. Hence, I run a test where I **intentionally** provide improper input parameters, so the program catches this and exits with an error (`exit 1`).

Problem: I want GitHub Actions to mark this test as success. I am aware of `continue-on-error: true` for a run. Still, this will mark any failed run as success, no matter whether my program exits intentionally with an error due to improper input parameters (as described above), or because there is a bug in my code which then should actually return a failed CI test. So far I am manually inspecting the Actions logs but there must be an automated way to catch this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it a specific command line that return the error, or a whole script execution? If it's a command line, I would suggest to use [this action](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/assert-command-line-output).

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yes, a CL basically. Will check the link, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

for a specific shell command you may just add ' || true ' after your command

```
function trigger_err { echo "triggering error"; return 2; }
 
trigger_err
triggering error

echo $?
2
 
trigger_err || true
triggering error

echo $?
0
```